# Already configure the /etc/hosts and /sites-available but still cant open the custom domain

Tags: php, apache, webmin

Im using Ubuntu 22.04

I tried to host my website for homework on my network. Before that im using localhost:8080 to open it . Now i tried using custom domain. Im following some tutorial to make from configure the /etc/hosts and sites-available here's my code
/etc.apache2/sites-available/bpguestbook.local.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
ServerName www.bpguestbook.local
ServerName bpguestbook.local

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 adminweb-VirtualBox
127.0.0.1:8080 bpguestbook.local
127.0.0.1:8080 www.bpguestbook.local
```

Note : i tried to host my website from my virtualbox ubuntu using webmin. Anyone got some tutorial to do it? and i cant open the 127.0.0.1:8080 on my other machine. (sorry for my english). Is there a way to open my website to other machine. Im using Codeigniter 4 too, thats why

the documentroot already correct. already do the `a2ensite` command. But it got trouble finding the site. Only can open it when using the localhost:8080...

I tried to change the bpguestbook.local.conf ip to the machine ip:8080 and etc/hosts too, but still cant open it (must use localhost:8080)

Comment: **i cant open the 127.0.0.1:8080 on my other machine** - of course, since 127.0.0.1 means local machine, so any other machine will visit itself

Comment: so how to change it xD

Comment: You cannot include ports in `hosts`. You would need to use `http://bpguestbook.local:8080/`

Comment: Still cant :(. Trouble to find...

Comment: and is there a way to host my website? what should i use to host it? i already got webmin